# Can I include a not persisted field in models file?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

In a Yesod scaffolded site, the `config/models` file syntax support the addition of a field not persisted in the database to an Entity description?

If yes, How can this be done?

Example:

```
User
    ident Text
    password Text Maybe
```

This `password` field will generate a column in the database. What I want is that the `User` data type generated have this `password` field but that the table `user` in the database does not have the `password` column. Is this possible?

I want to only persist the `ident` field, but want to use the following data type in my haskell code:

```
data User = User {ident :: Text, password :: Maybe Text}
```

Comment: What do you mean by non persisted field ? Can you explain with a example possibly.

Comment: Thank you @Sibi. Edited to include an example. HTH

Comment: As far as I know, persistent doesn't support that. But this seems to me like a [case of XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you say what you are trying to achieve via that ?

Comment: I want the benefit of automatic generation of json instances and Entity datatype, but one field is always null in the database. I could wrap the Entity in another type that have this field, but I found it much complicated the access to the fields this way. The actual code is the `Task` entity in this [models](https://github.com/frt/happyscheduler/blob/master/config/models#L13) file and this [instance declaration](https://github.com/frt/happyscheduler/blob/master/Model.hs#L16). I am looking for ways to make it cleaner.